# Confirmation email sent to user in vb.net to mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, confirmation-email

Just want to ask if there is some way to add automatic email confirmation to vb.net website. 
I want that user create new account in the website and the website sent the confirmation link to them. Only if the confirmation email is clicked the user will be able to fully register.

I know that there are ways with build in login page from vb. But I'm using my own login. Mainly becouse the database where user connect is MySql.

something like this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/implement-the-registration-verification-pattern

Any idea where to look? most of the google search links are with php or to Microsoft Sql.

Thanks in advance for any good link or solution.

Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, when an user registers the account, you generate a confirmation # (I will use GUID), then send the user an email with the confirmation link. the confirmation link is the url of the confirmation page with the confirmation # as parameter, i.e. www.mysite.com/confirmation.aspx?code={guid} . you save the confirmation code in the database with the user account table (it could be in the same table or a separated table). the user has to click the confirmation url to confirm. when confirm, you just need to check whether the code is the same as the Guid in the database.

Basically, the process is the same and it has no much relation with mySQL or SQL Server.

here is an example, although it is C#, the same process, just a little bit different syntax in code:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp_net/registration-confirmation-system/index.html

also

[asp.net confirmation mail send link that contains a unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767182/asp-net-confirmation-mail-send-link-that-contains-a-unique-identifier)